# joomla when searching in homepage show nothing

Tags: search, joomla

I have a search module on the home page and when I use it it stays on the homepage and shows nothing and when I use it on other parts of the website it works. When I use the search on the home page it shows this URL in the address bar:

http://127.0.0.1/esg/index.php/component/search/?searchword=test&searchphrase=all&Itemid=435

I've tried to check the PHP file of the module in /modules/mod_search but it seems normal because it works elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Create a menu item of type "Search - Search Results" in Joomla and then clear your Joomla cache. That should fix your problem.